# valgrind compains on struct sockaddr_nl

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, valgrind

I think the common pattern in sockets programming for sending messages is :

```
static const struct sockaddr_nl snl = {
   .nl_family = AF_NETLINK
};
return sendto(nl->fd, buf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &snl, sizeof(snl));
```

where `struct sockaddr_*` depends on the socket type. The above code will cause `valgrind` complain:

```
Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
```

This is clearly because the rest of members of the `struct sockaddr_nl` are not initialized.

This is how it looks on my system (ubuntu 16.04):

```
struct sockaddr_nl {
        __kernel_sa_family_t    nl_family;      /* AF_NETLINK   */
        unsigned short  nl_pad;         /* zero         */
        __u32           nl_pid;         /* port ID      */
        __u32           nl_groups;      /* multicast groups mask */
};
```

So my question - is it safe to initialize `nl_pid` and `nl_groups` to zero in case of `sendto()` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valgrind complains about the msg argument having some uninitialised byte(s),
not about snl.
It is the memory pointed to by buf which contains uninitialised bytes.

You can use --track-origins=yes to confirm where uninitialised bytes 
have been created.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, thanks! The option is `--track-origins`